# Multiplas requisições ajax usando jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Possuo este código repetidas vezes e queria simplificar isso em uma espécie de *plugin* ou função. Informações que geralmente utilizo, o Type => '*get*' ou '*post*' e a *url*, e o retorno eu trato na sequencia com *jquery*.

```
$.ajax({
    type: '',
    url: '' ,
    dataType : 'json',
    //data: jsonString,
    beforeSend: function () {
        //SPINNER
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    },
    complete: function () {

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Em minhas requisições ajax normalmente crio uma classe js e lá ficam métodos genéricos, porém por semântica acabo separando gets, posts.. 
Segue abaixo um exemplo que uso para Post

```
function BaseEnviaPost(url, objeto, onSuccess, onError) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: objeto,
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            onSuccess();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            onError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Quando preciso usar, a chamada fica simplificada assim:

```
var success = function (data) {
   //ação
}

var error = function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //ação
}

function BaseEnviaPost() {
    var url = "";
    var data = {};
    BaseEnviaCreate(url, data, success, error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara, acho que da mais jogo explorar uma tecnologias mais recentes que Dao uma flexibilidade maior com Ajax calls. Por exemplo... angularjs, facilita bastante. voce criaria um serviço e nesse serviço usaria `$http.get(<url>)` e pronto. Enfim. fica a dica mas não responde a pergunta.

agora, voce poria sim escrever uma funçãozinha mas ou menos assim pra resolver o teu problema:

```
function (url, type, successFn, errorFn = undefined){
   // escreve os códigos aqui...
}
```

Na real, nao ajuda nada fazer isso, é trocar 6 por meia dúzia. Da uma olhada no angularjs, super fácil!

> https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_services.asp

Comment: Pois então , estou pensando no angularjs pela praticidade de algumas coisas, a separação de camadas é muito bem organizada mas me falta tempo para aprender angularjs e fazer um sistema com logins e controle de niveis de acesso no momento. Mas Obrigado!

Comment: É Carlos, mas voce vai ver que a organização e praticidade do Angular vai te salvar muito tempo la na frente. Usar libs tipo auth0 também ajuda bastante! mas enfim... boa sorte!

Answer (score 0):

Função:

```
function funcaoAjax(type, url, dateType, beforesend, success, complete, error){
  $.ajax({
      type: type,
      url: url,
      dataType: dateType,
      beforeSend: beforesend,
      success: success,
      complete: complete,
      error: error
  });

}
```

Para chamar:

```
funcaoAjax("POST", "minnhaurl", "POST", function(){
  // código do beforesend
}, 
function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
  // código do success
},
function(){
  // código do complete
},
function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
  // código do error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Cria uma função à volta desse ajax com alguns pressupostos que podem ser mudadod, e usa o facto de o ajax retornar um objeto tipo promise. Aí vais repetir bastante menos código.

```js
function ajax(options) {
  return $.ajax({
    method: options.method || 'GET',
    url: options.url || './meu/endpoint/favorito,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: options.data || {},
    beforeSend: function() {
      //SPINNER
    },
  }).fail(function() {
    // aqui tratas dos erros que possam haver
    console.log('Erro...');
  });
}
```

E depois para usar:

```
ajax({url: './endpoint1').then(function(resposta){
    console.log(resposta);
});
```